# Automatic performance testing of Scala libraries

Tags: performance, scala, performance-testing

Do any Scala testing libraries help with performance tests? Can't find anything relevant in ScalaTest or specs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SPerformance is heading towards this goal: http://github.com/jsuereth/sperformance/

Answer (score 10):

[ScalaMeter](http://axel22.github.com/scalameter/) (hat tip to Alexandar Procopec): a microbenchmarking and performance regression testing framework for the JVM platform that allows expressing performance tests in a way which is both simple and concise.

- It can be used both from Scala and Java.
- write performance tests in a DSL similar to ScalaTest and ScalaCheck
- specify test input data
- specify how test results are collected
- organize performance tests hierarchically